# Programmatically access values of Discussions and the Replies in Sharepoint 2013 Community site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Hi how do I access the value of **Discussions** and the Replies in the community site, for example how to get the value of Body of the Discussion and Body of the Reply of that discussion.

Is there are two different list to store discussions and Replies of the discussion or the same "Discussions List" storing both the values. I'm having troble getting the values of the discussion. When im tring to get the value of the discussion its giving the value of the replies.

Anyone has tried this out please give me some feedbacks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To fetch the Discussions and Replies separately, you can use the following query parameter in your REST query:

**For Discussion Topics**

```
/_api/lists/getByTitle(‘listname‘)/items?$filter=ContentType eq ‘Discussion’
or
/_api/lists/getByTitle(‘listname‘)/items?$filter=FSObjType eq 1
```

**For Discussion Replies**

```
/_api/lists/getByTitle(‘listname‘)/items?$filter=ContentType eq ‘Message’
or
/_api/lists/getByTitle(‘listname‘)/items?$filter=FSObjType eq 0
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The list items in discussion board with parent id = null are the discussion topic and with parent id = some values are the replies to dicussion topic..

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint’s Discussion lists are sort of like Document Sets, in that the original post is a Discussion Content Type which inherits from Folder and the replies are the Message Content Type, which inherits from Item. So there aren’t any Documents involved, but Discussions (Discussion list) are once again Folders.

https://sharepointeducation.wordpress.com/2016/12/06/get-all-replies-of-a-discussion-in-sharepoint-2013/